# How to do filtering for many entities of many DataServices in one common class?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

Tier database and every single table has a DataSetId and I absolutely want to be sure that the data is always partitioned correctly.

Currently I'm using the QueryInterceptor attribute but it's messy and overly repetitive and prone to errors. Some new Dev could add a new table and forget to filter by DataSetId, or just rename a table.  So I've put this in a base class but the IQuerable properties of my repository are never called.

I have a "CoreRepository" class that inherits from ObjectContext, and each of my IQueryable collections uses "CoreObjectSet". CoreObjectSet extends ObjectSet by always adding an expression to filter by DataSetId.  When used directly this works fine. But when used for a DataService the Get accessor for the collections on the Repository are never called by the DataService.  It appears to be cheating and not using them at all and accessing the data directly.

Is there a way to get the DataService to access through the repository class correctly (And still get the efficiency of passing through the query as SQL)?

If this is the behaviour why even make DataService of T anyway if it's not even going to use the class? For the ADO team to just ignore it and use the edmx directly seems like a hack.

Thanks
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way around it is to use a T4 template to generate the DataService. I much prefer a base class or some kind of reusable handler but ADO has given me no choice here.